# SQL Server login fails with JDBC connection

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jdbc, windows-authentication

I have attempted to get a JDBC to SQL Server (mixed authentication) connection on a Windows VM and I am stumped. I am working with a Spring Boot 2.1 and SQL Server 13.0 system. Trying to connect to the database to create APIs and I cannot connect.

I have tried via application properties with the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DB_411YS20;integratedSecurity=true
spring.datasource.username="server's username"
spring.datasource.password="server's password"
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties..hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I have also tried the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.cs.odu.yellow.ODU.Connect",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class AppConfig {

    private String dbDriverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private String dbUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DB_411YS20;integratedSecurity=true";
    private String dbUsername = "server's username";
    private String dbUserPassword = "server's password";

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    DataSource dataSource(Environment env) throws SQLException{

        DriverManagerDataSource mssql = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        mssql.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClassName);
        mssql.setUrl(dbUrl);
//        mssql.setUsername(dbUsername);
//        mssql.setPassword(dbUserPassword);
        return mssql;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean (DataSource dataSource, Environment env){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("411yellowEntityManager");
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.cs.odu.yellow.ODU.Connect");
        em.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties(env));

        return em;
    }

    private Properties jpaProperties(Environment env){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", dbUsername);
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", dbUserPassword);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        return properties;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return tm;
    }

}
```

The stack trace is saying that the login has failed:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'CS\411yello'. ClientConnectionId:28ced5ed-6995-4866-b4f5-7d5430cc03e4
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:328) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:142) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:112) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d33032.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$9(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d33032$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9ec1ebba.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d33032.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:455) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.cs.odu.yellow.ODU.Connect.OduConnectApplication.main(OduConnectApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'CS\411yello'. ClientConnectionId:28ced5ed-6995-4866-b4f5-7d5430cc03e4
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Please help!

Comment: You're using integrated security, and the user `CS\411yello` could not be authenticated or is not allowed to login on the database server.

Comment: Hi Mark, I am able to log into SSMS just fine using windows auth, which is the CS\411yello login.

Comment: I'd recommend checking the SQL Server logs if it contains anything related to this authentication failure to see if it provides more details on the problem.

Comment: Problem solved. I deleted the JPA facet and it works as advertised.

Comment: hockeytowndev what do you delete?